# How to output html on a custom location with a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

How can I use a self-made Wordpress plugin to output for example a custom menu or custom HTML to a specific location? The only places I managed to output content is in `wp_head` and `wp_footer`, but is it possible to get content to show up anywhere else? Is it even possible to force the plugin to output the HTML for example inside a specific `div` or a DOM element?

---

### Example scenarios

1. I want to add a custom button that triggers a menu or modal, but the button needs to be located inside the header and I also need a place for the modal HTML before the footer (example).
2. I want to add custom made "social share buttons" to every page and need a place to output the HTML after the page title.

---

Just to give you a feeling of what I'm trying to do...

Maybe I'm just way off track. I am new to this, but I am eager to learn.

"Teach me the ways of the force"

Appreciate any help, Thanks :)

Comment: You could use some built in filters http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39918/wordpress-hooks-filters-insert-before-content-or-after-title perhaps, but if this is theme specific it might make more sense to edit the appropriate theme files

Comment: This is what [action hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) are for